# when i Install new apk,get this Error : "Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method..... "

Tags: android, xamarin.android

**Error**

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser
>   android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

**CS**

```
Java.IO.File oFile = new Java.IO.File(AppPara.sAppSetupPath+ "/" + 
AppPara.sAppPackage);
if (oFile.Exists())
{
   if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.N)
  {
   **Android.Net.Uri apkUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(activity, 
   "StartNetApp.Android.fileprovider", oFile);**//this line show that 
    error!!

   Intent oIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionInstallPackage); 
    oIntent.SetData(apkUri);                                                
   oIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission); 
   activity.StartActivity(oIntent);
   } 
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/Icon">
<provider
 android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
 android:authorities="StartNetApp.Android.fileprovider"
 android:enabled="false"
 android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
 <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_path" />
    </provider>

 </application>
```

**file_provider_path**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path   name="external_files"    path="." />
  <root-path   name="external_files"    path="/storage/"/>
</paths>
```

pls help me!

Comment: Where did you put your file_provider_paths? You need to ensure that it must be in res>xml folder.

Comment: yes , it's in res>xml floder

Comment: What happened if you remove <root-path   name="external_files"    path="/storage/"/>? You already have external_files at the top.

Comment: I was try it.but not work.

Comment: it's ok now!!  use "GetExternalFilesDir(null)" get the path ,and add  "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />" to  AndroidManifest.